# Remove only one duplicate value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare the value in Sheet "TransferUt" Cell A1 with range A in sheet "Inne", to clear contents of the **first** occurrence in cell A and B (Sheet "Inne").

There will be a number of duplicates and single values in "Inne".

I have found and edited the following code (only the bit I have a problem with). It removes **all** duplicated values in "Inne", column A, that matches cell A1 in Sheet "TransferUt". I want to remove one at the time.

```vb
Dim LastRowInRange  As Long, RowCounter As Long
LastRowInRange = Sheets("Inne").Range("A:A").Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

For RowCounter = LastRowInRange To 1 Step -1
    If Sheets("Inne").Range("A" & RowCounter) = Sheets("TransferUt").Range("A1") Then
        Sheets("Inne").Rows(RowCounter).Cells(2).ClearContents
        Sheets("Inne").Rows(RowCounter).Cells(1).ClearContents
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Add an 'exit for' as the last statement in the If block of the  'For RowCounter' loop

Comment: Find the first occurence with MATCH and clear only that row?

Comment: @freeflow Can you give me an example on what that line would look like?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Can you please provide the code for that?

Comment: @Jonstorp If you can't figure out where to put the 'exit for' based on my comment then the best advice I can give you is to stop whatever coding you are trying to do and work your way through a VBA tutorial  Questions on topics as basic and as fundamental as yours are not really the subject material for this forum

Comment: @freeflow I am trying my best to learn and understand how to write code. If i understand you correctly; My question is to basic for this forum?

Comment: @Jonstorp  This forum is for experienced amateurs and professionals who have encountered an unexpected problem or poorly documented API and have exhausted all other areas of research.  Unfortunately many posters don't realise this, and many responders do not enforce the ethos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub test()
Dim ThisRow As Long

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    'first, check if value from TransferUt.A1 exist in Inne column A
    If .CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inne").Range("A:A"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TransferUt").Range("A1")) > 1 Then
        'If it exists then clear only the first occurrence
        ThisRow = .Match(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TransferUt").Range("A1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inne").Range("A:A"), 0)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inne").Range("A" & ThisRow & ":B" & ThisRow).ClearContents 'delete cell contents
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

The code first will check if your target value exists **duplicated** in `Inne` doing a count. If the count is 0 or 1 it means it does not exist or it's a single value (no duplicates in column A). If the count is more than 1, then clear the contents of the cells A and B in `Inne`

Note that clearing contents won't delete the row, it just leave both cells blank.

Comment: That worked beautifully on the duplicates!!! I envy your abilites to write VBA! However, i want the macro to clear the cells in "Inne" columns A:B even if there only is one occurence of that perticular value. Dont know how to explain better.. maybe remove the first occurence of the value from "transferUt" cell A1 in sheet "Inne" column A every time?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with this piece of code:

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()
Dim C As Range
Dim Endr As Range
Dim Fullr As Range
Set Endr = Range("A1").End(xlDown)
Set Fullr = Range("A1", Endr)

For Each C In Fullr:
  If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Fullr, C.Value) > 1 Then
     C.ClearContents
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

So, as you can see:

`Endr` is the last cell of column "A" which contains a value.
`Fullr` is the entire range of column "A" which contains values.

You run over the entire `Fullr` and for each cell, you count the amount of times its value appears in column "A" and when it appears more than one time, the value gets deleted. Like that, the value of `CountIf()` will reduce until only single values are left.

Comment: I copied your code into my exsiting macro, replacing my own code. But it didnt do anything. Didnt remove any duplicate value from sheet "Inne". I dont understand how your code uses cell A1 in sheet "TransferUt" as a reference when looking though column A in Sheet "Inne"?

Comment: And to make things more clear. Every time there is a value in "TranferUt" Cell A1, the macro needs to search sheet "Inne" column A and remove one occurence. Even if it there only is one..